# How to install and configure Apache Ambari on RHEL without internet connection

Tags: hadoop, installation, cluster-computing

How to install and configure Apache Ambari on RHEL without internet connection??  I can copy the files to this server from my local machine which has internet connection

Comment: Other options are floppy disks or CDs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow these docs:

http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-1.6.1.0/bk_using_Ambari_book/content/ambari-chap1.html

Specifically, installing Ambari and the Stack using Local Repositories is covered here:

http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-1.6.1.0/bk_using_Ambari_book/content/ambari-chap1-6.html

Answer (score -1):

**Step-1** Download tar file using this below link
Here's [a link](http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos7/2.x/updates/2.6.1.5/ambari-2.6.1.5-centos7.tar.gz)!
you will get ambari setup using (http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos7/2.x/updates/2.6.1.5/ambari-2.6.1.5-centos7.tar.gz)

**Step-2** Download 4 RPM dependency about postgres92 which will need during installation . 
first of all install these RPM at a time using command rpm -ivf

These name are:-
**1.** **postgresql92-postgresql9.2.18-1.el7.x86_64.rpm**
Here's [a link](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-sclo-rh-x86_64/postgresql92-postgresql-9.2.18-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html)!

**2.** **postgresql92-postgresql-libs-9.2.18-1.el7.x86_64.rpm***
Here's [a link](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-sclo-rh-x86_64/postgresql92-postgresql-libs-9.2.18-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html)!

**3.** **postgresql92-postgresql-server-9.2.18-1.el7.x86_64.rpm***
Here's [a link](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-sclo-rh-x86_64/postgresql92-postgresql-server-9.2.18-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html)!

**4.** ***postgresql92-postgresql-runtime-9.2.18-1.el7.x86_64.rpm***
Here's [a link](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-sclo-rh-x86_64/postgresql92-runtime-1.1-20.el7.x86_64.rpm.html)!

**Note: install all 4 above RPM then ....  follow below steps**

**Step-3** go to ambari-server.rpm folder and install it
     **command:  yum install ambari-server.rpm**

**Step-4** now, start command:  **ambari-servet setup** 
and chose you all option below whatever will come after this command .

**make sure that while doing all above things you will have to be a root user**

Thanks hope it will work fine